# How to predict rating in Image-based recommender system?

Tags: recommender-system

Currently I have metadata files, train _rating and test_rating. I have built a model that allows users to input an image and suggest products with similar images.

I wanted to make my image-based model capable of predicting ratings, so I used Ridge Regression and a list of training item features (extracted by pretrain model) to build a rating prediction model. However, I see that this seems to be used for Content-based while mine is Image-based. Can I ask if the way I did it was correct?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? As written, it sounds like both methods make use of the image and as a result are both image-based

Comment: @Karl i just want to know the way to predict rating between user and item in image-based recommendation system.

Comment: @Karl I am building a Hybrid recommender with a combination of Collaborative recommender and Image-based recommender. The data function predicts the hybrid's rating will be 0.4*ratingOfCollab + 0.6*ratingOfImage. I want my Image recommender to be able to predict ratings so I can compare the rmse when using Collaborative recommener alone and when combining it with Image-based